# Joining complex mysql queries from the same table

Tags: mysql

This works:

```
    SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT 
SUM(count) AS valid,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ref_url,'http://',''),'https://',''),'www.',''),'/',1) AS sDomain 
FROM ref_records
WHERE user_id = 9507
GROUP BY sDomain 
ORDER BY 1 DESC) 
as A

INNER JOIN

( SELECT 
SUM(invalid) AS invalid,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ref_url,'http://',''),'https://',''),'www.',''),'/',1) AS sDomain
FROM ref_records
WHERE user_id = 9507
GROUP BY sDomain 
ORDER BY 1 DESC) 
as B


on A.sDomain=B.sDomain
```

However it outputs the following table:

```
valid | sDomain | invalid | sDomain
```

Now I would like the same results to be merged as follows:

```
sDomain | valid | invalid
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Tried with union but it only summed up the result of the two sum queries... not what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just select unique items and sum of other item in your select then use group by statement.

check the following statement:

```
select A.sDomain ,sum(valid) as valid, sum(invalid)
from A INNER JOIN B ON A.sDomain=B.sDomain
group By A.sDomain
```

Comment: I don't know how to apply this to my query since sum is complex as you can see in the example.

Comment: you just replace.
{SELECT * 
FROM}
with 
{SELECT A.sDomain ,valid, invalid
FROM
}
in your query and you get the result you want.